# React and Flowtype - inherit class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

Lets assume that I have

```
// Foo.js
type PropsType = { cool: boolean };
class Foo extends React.Component<PropsType> {}

// Bar.js
import Foo from './Foo';

type PropsBar = { temp: string };
class Bar extends Foo {
  test() {
     this.props.cool; // there is no error
     this.props.temp;
                ^^^^ Property not found in object type  
  }
}
```

My question is, how to pass additional `Props` to `Bar` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your super class generic. Just as `React.Component` is generic, so can your classes and functions be as well.

You can make a declaration such as a class or function generic by introducing a type parameter.

Let us make `Foo` generic

```
export default class Foo<T> extends React.Component<FooProps & T> {}
```

Note the intersection type, written `FooProps & T`, that is passed to the generic super class `React.Component`. This means that `Foo.prototype.props` will have the properties declared in `FooProps` and also any properties declared by `T`.

Now when we use `Foo`, such as in an `extends` clause, we need to specify a type for `T`.

```
type BarProps = { temp: string };

export default class Bar extends Foo<BarProps> {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log(this.props.temp);
  }
}
```

If you want to maintain simplicity for consumers of `Foo` that do not add additional props, you can specify a default type for `T` as in

```
export default class Foo<T = {}> extends React.Component<FooProps & T> {}

export class Bar extends Foo {}
```

Note: All of the syntax above is valid in both Flow and TypeScript.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your explanation :)

Comment: Glad I could help